# Strip HTML tags from Scala String

Tags: parsing, scala, string, lift, strip-tags

I am developing web app using Scala and Lift framework. I have record in DB which contains html perex of page

```
<b>Hi all, this is perex</b>
```

And in one scenario I need to print to user this perex, but without html tags.

```
Hi all, this is perex
```

It is possible to do this in Scala? Because I tried to look with Google, but with no success.

thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the string is valid XML then you can use:

`scala.xml.XML.loadString("<b>Hi all, this is parex</b>").text`

If it's not valid XML, then you can use `scala.util.matching.Regex` or an HTML parsing library like http://jsoup.org/

Comment: I am using your solution right now and it seems it works. I had to wrap my String to <span> tag to work even with "<b>Hi</b> name" string. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd rather use `scala.xml.parsing.XhtmlParser` to parse the HTML. Better chance of parsing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found was to use [cyberneko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net) to parse your string and do some "clever" SAX event handling.

cyberneko will parse your HTML even if it's invalid, which is the case for the vast majority of the HTML you're likely to encounter in the wild.

If you register a custom `ContentHandler` that essentially ignores all but the `character` events and just append those to a string builder, you'll get a good first approximation, with an annoying flaw: words separated by a block element will end up concatenated (`for<br/>example` => `forexample`).

A better solution is to get a list of all block elements, and have your `ContentHandler` listen to `startElement` events. If the element is a block one, just append a space character to your string builder.

Note that while this seems to work fine, it might not be perfect for your use case. `<br/>` is not, for example, turned into a line break. It shouldn't be too much work to add this if it's required, though.

Answer (score 0):

[TagSoup](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html) should meet your requirement to parse a realworld html file.

sbt dependencies,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" % "tagsoup" % "1.2.1"
```

Sample code,

```
object TagSoupXmlLoader {

  private val factory = new SAXFactoryImpl()

  def get(): XMLLoader[Elem] = {
    XML.withSAXParser(factory.newSAXParser())
  }
}
```

usage,

```
val root = TagSoupXmlLoader.get().load("http://www.google.com")
println(root)
```

Comment: For those who wonder, this example needs a number of imports. I use sbt, so I load `TagSoup` and other dependencies using sbt:
`libraryDependencies += "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" % "tagsoup" % "1.2.1"` and then the import: `import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl`. You also need to import Scala XML, e.g.: `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.1.1"` with `import scala.xml.{Elem, XML}` and finally,
`import scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader`